# Who exactly are Charanas?

Tags: scripture, terminology

In Mahabharata and many other scriptures, there is a class of elite people called Charanas.

For example, consider the following excerpt from Mahabharata

> The men carried the message in a trice to the court. And the citizens
> of Hastinapura, hearing of the arrival of thousands of **Charanas** and Munis, were filled with wonder. And it was soon after
> sunrise that they began to come out in numbers with their wives and
> children to behold those ascetics. Seated in all kinds of cars and
> conveyances by thousands, vast numbers of Kshatriyas with their wives,
> and Brahmanas with theirs came out.
>
> [[Section 126, Sambhava Parva, Adi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01127.htm)

Who are called Charanas? What is meant by Charana?

Comment: They are an intelligent, bird-like species. They may be the same as the Garudas.

Answer (score 2):

Charanas are celestial beings mentioned in many puranas and itihasas.

In [mahabharata](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/mahabharata/d/doc118373.html),

> Accompanied by the sages and the Charanas [a species of celestial
> beings like the seraphim and cherubim], Kunti and her children
> appeared outside the city gates of Hastinapura.

In [Ramayana](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/content?language=dv&field_kanda_tid=5&field_sarga_value=1&field_sloka_value=1&=Apply),

> Hanuman, crusher of enemies resolved to find the whereabouts of Sita,
> carried away by Ravana. He followed the path of the Charanas,
> celestial bards.